# My laptop doesn't support NVMe system.

Tags: ssd, pci-express, nvme

I wanted to replace my old M.2 SSD (Plextor PX-G128M6e) to a new bigger and faster M.2. So i got a new WD Black M.2 PCIe with NVMe system and I send my laptop back to my manufacturer to replace the SSD for me. They reply to me that my laptop didn't pass the haswll test and my laptop don't support NVMe. So my questions are

1.What is haswell system? i tried to google it but still don't really understand.
2.What is the real reason that my laptop cannot support NVMe?
3.What M.2 PCIe that my laptop can support?
4.Does that mean my laptop is too old? Bought it 4 years ago

Thanks in advance

Comment: I really must question the sanity of sending the SSD to the manufacturer(!) to have the SSD replaced with a part you provided. Go to a local PC repair shop and have them do it if you aren’t comfortable with it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[Haswell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_(microarchitecture)) is the code name of a family of Intel CPUs introduces in 2013.

M.2 SSDs can be connected via SATA or NVMe. Some PCs support both, others only SATA or NVMe. If your device supports only SATA you can't use NVMe M2 SSDs.

Comment: It’s even worse. The SSD he currently has is a PCIe device, but it emulates a SATA controller.